# Applying specific styling to GeoJSON layer in Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, style

I am new to Leaflet.js and I would like to apply specific styling to the Geojson layer>

This is my code so far:

```
# geojson data
var geojson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              78.25218200683594,
              17.169658620146077
            ],
            [
              78.24806213378905,
              17.124385992430643
            ],
            [
              78.3270263671875,
              17.128323180676293
            ],
            [
              78.32771301269531,
              17.17097070556175
            ],
            [
              78.25218200683594,
              17.169658620146077
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


# map id
map = map_d9d7d7866ebf4532b5adbeac7253c85f

test = "test"

L.geoJson(geojson, {
onEachFeature: function(feature,layer) {
layer.bindTooltip(test);
}
}).addTo(map);


# styling options
var exteriorStyle = {
    "stroke": "blue",
    "stroke-width": 3,
    "stroke-opacity": 0.7,
    "fill": "#494949",
    "fill-opacity": 0
};

# map geojson layer with styling
var exteriorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {style: exteriorStyle}).addTo(map);
```

However, when I run it, I get the following:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

I would like this result as specified in the styling:

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#geojson-style carefully.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I read that documentation before but I still don't understand. Could you explain please with my example?

Comment: The documentation states that the `style` option must be a `Function` (which shall return a set of [`Path` options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path)). Now look at your code and tell me: is the value of your `style` option a `Function`?

Comment: It's definitely not a function. How can turn in into a function please? Sorry I'm very new to JavaScript. Could you give me a example here?

Comment: Read [the tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/). And make sure you don't add the GeoJSON data twice, since adding a second `L.GeoJSON` with the same data to a Leaflet map will use the default blue scheme, will display on top of the other instance, and you'll be confused.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but is that the reason why it's not working? In the documentation it says I can style GeoJSON two ways so I still don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Because you're adding it twice, and you still have `stroke: 'blue'` instead of `stroke: 'red'` and `fill: '#494949'` instead of `fill: false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110599/discussion-between-ishack-marshook-and-ivansanchez).